# Xively error using json

Tags: json, xively

I have an error on xively regarding the connection when being updated using json and socket.

```
{"status":403,"headers":{"DATE":"Mon, 02 Nov 2015 07:57:21 GMT","CONTENT_TYPE":"application/json; charset=utf-8","TRANSFER_ENCODING":"chunked","CONNECTION":"close"},"body":{"title":"Forbidden","errors":"You do not have the necessary permissions to access this resource"},"token":"0x12345","resource":"/v2/feeds/FEED_ID/"}
```

Kindly help !!